# Modify Connection String to add host name

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to add host's name into connection string?

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Mapping.WksModels.csdl|res://*/Mapping.WksModels.ssdl|res://*/Mapping.WksModels.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MyDb;password=test;persist security info=True;user id=test&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

`MyDb` in `Data source=MyDb` should be the host name (not the db name)

Comment: then how to include the database name? because the connectionStrings above is working fine for me..

Comment: `Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDB;` first is the server, second is the database

Comment: I encountered this...'initial catalog' is an invalid connection string attribute

Comment: Hmmm...Triple check, same error... Can I use IP instead of PC-name for server?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

string conn = "DATA SOURCE=YOURhostname.com:1521/DBNAME;USER ID=YOURUSERNAME;PASSWORD=YOURPASSWORD";

Do not add any additional spaces or quotes. Good luck.